# How to add a custom label in shipping address form in Magento2.2.5?

Tags: magento2, custom, shipping-address, labels

I want to add a only a **label - just for informing a user** in shipping address form in Magento2.2.5?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: static label ??

Comment: Yes it is static label..

Comment: check out page ???

Comment: Yes in checkout page only..

Comment: You can try below file path and override in your custom file, for static shipping address label.
magento/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/list.html

<span data-bind="i18n: 'Shipping address Label'"></span>